# Storing printer commands as a variable

Tags: c#, printing, webapi

I am sending [FGL print commands](https://www.tls-bocasystems.com/pdf/tls-boca-systems-uk-div-programming-guide.pdf) to a Boca printer.

I have the commands hard-coded but I would like to have some way of modifying the print commands if needed, except the entire print command uses a List of tickets so it is a mix of variable data and print commands.

Is it possible to code this is a way that stores the print command as a variable?  Thanks.

**UPDATE**:  I reduced the code snippet because the print command is actually much longer, then realized I was really only looking to change one line on the ticket: "Access our map, audio, and more at foo.org/guide."  That text is easily stored in a configuration file.  Also, added suggestion from [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley).

```
int i = 0;
string printerCommands = "";

foreach (var ticket in tickets)
{
    if (tickets.Count > 0)
    {
        if (i == tickets.Count - 1) 
        {
            printerCommands = "<RU><RC600,200><QRV2><QR6,0,1,0>{" + ticket.uuid + "}<F3><HW1,1><RC380,760>" + ticket.eventName + "<RC340,760>" + ticket.ticketTypeName + "<RC300,760>$" + ticket.unitPrice + "<p>";
        }
        else
        {
            printerCommands = "<RU><RC600,200><QRV2><QR6,0,1,0>{" + ticket.uuid + "}<F3><HW1,1><RC380,760>" + ticket.eventName + "<RC340,760>" + ticket.ticketTypeName + "<RC300,760>$" + ticket.unitPrice + "<q>";
        }
    }
    response = Transmit(printerCommands);
    ps.status = response;
    ps.dataPrinted = "uuid: " + ticket.uuid + ", eventDateTime: " + ticket.eventDateTime + ", eventName: " + ticket.eventName + ", ticketTypeName: " + ticket.ticketTypeName;

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I's not completely clear what you're looking for, but it looks to me that only the last tag is different between the two, so you could do:

```
    printerCommands = "<RU><RC600,200><QRV2><QR6,0,1,0>{" 
                    + ticket.uuid + "}<F3><HW1,1><RC380,760>" 
                    + ticket.eventName + "<RC340,760>" 
                    + ticket.ticketTypeName + "<RC300,760>$"
                    + ticket.unitPrice;

    if (i == tickets.Count - 1) 
    {
        printerCommands += "<p>";
    }
    else
    {
        printerCommands += "<q>";
    }
```

There are probably ways to simplify the initial string creation as well = maybe put a list of tags and variables in a list? Or use a constant format string and "inject" the variables?

You could also use Linq to generate the command, but that's just syntactic sugar on top of the loop. There's nothing wrong with building up the string in a loop if it's simple to understand and has no performance issues.